# How to exclude attributes when looking using .each

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

I try to loop through attributes like this:

```
<% student.account.attributes.each do |value| %>
    <td><%= value %></td>
<% end %>
```

which is ok. But, how can I exclude certain attributes, from being looped? I used an array like ['one', 'two', 'three'] where 'one', 'two', and 'three' are the values to exclude (or, if this is easier - include).

**Edit:**

As suggested by @Vysakh Sreenivasan I finally used this:

```
<% exclude_keys = ['one', 'two', 'three'] %>
<% student.account.attributes.each do |key, value| %>
  <td><%= value unless exclude_keys.include? key %></td>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if student.account.attributes is an array

**One way**

```
<% student.account.attributes.each do |value| %>
<td><%= value unless ["one", "two", "three"].include? value %></td>
<% end %>
```

**Another way**

```
<% exclude_values = ["one" , "two", "three"] %>
<% (student.account.attributes - exclude_values).each do |value| %>
   <td> <%= value %> </td> 
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you! One problem: "-" does not seem to work with hashes, i got an error. My final approach is a mixture of your answer, I´ll post them seperately as answer.

Comment: I thought it was an array and suggested another way. Anyway first approach should work both for array and hash.